# Can quantum theory predict the radioactive properties of given element?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radioactivity

I think there is no known physical theory that predicts the radioactive properties of elements in the periodic table. I guess it would be great if we can predict theoretically the radioactive properties (stability, fission-ability, half-life, types of emitted particles, and their energies ) given the number of neutrons and protons in the nucleus.

> Given the number of neutrons and protons in a nucleus of an element, Can quantum theory predict *all* radioactive properties of that element (stability, fission-ability, half-life, types of emitted particles, and their energies)?

[image]

(Figure from this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/482862/3103)

Comment: Nuclear physics, based in quantum mechanics, can do reasonably well. So I’m a bit unclear on exactly what you are asking.

Comment: try the shell model, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model

Comment: @JonCuster Given the number of neutrons and protons in a nucleus, Can quantum physics predict _all_ radioactive properties of that element (stability, fission-ability, half-life, types of emitted particles, and their energies )?

Comment: I think that you need an overview on nuclear physics. But, one paper I read recently is 'Calculation of Fission Neutron Spectra for Spontaneous Fission of $^{240}$Pu, $^{238}$Pu and $^{242}$Pu', (R.L. Walsh et al., Nuclear Science and Engineering 108:1 109-115 (2017) - I think that gives some idea of what can be calculated these days.